# How I can import all js and all css that reside in resourced folder, in my vite config without need to define them one by one?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite

In my laravel 10 project I load a js as:

```
@vite(['resources/js/myjs.js'])
```

And my `vite.config.js` contains the follwoing settings

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/style.css',
                'resources/css/another-style.css',

                'resources/js/main.js',
                'resources/js/my.js',
                'resources/js/myjs.js',

                'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        inject({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'common_functions':'resources/js/common_functions.js',
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: [
                "js/modules/*",
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

But if I need another js file I should place it in `vite.config.js` thus makes the divelopment kinda slow because I need to place any new ccs or js into the `vite.config.js` that due to rush of development I may forget it.

Is there a way to conveniently for the vite to look any files defined in `resources/css` and `resources/js` folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik there is no option to pass wildcard *. According to: [docu](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/how-to-load-multiple-files-via-vite-config-using-wildcards). We have to do it programmatically , maybe like this, where it traverses through the folders and get the path of the files, you could the just spread the `...pageStyles` into the object, where you want to insert the filepaths.

```
function getFilesFromDir(dir, fileTypes) {
    const filesToReturn = [];

    function walkDir(currentPath) {
        const files = readdirSync(currentPath);
        for (let i in files) {
            const curFile = resolve(currentPath, files[i]);
            if (readdirSync(curFile, { withFileTypes: true }).some(dirent => dirent.isDirectory())) {
                walkDir(curFile);
            } else {
                if (fileTypes.indexOf(curFile.split('.').pop()) !== -1) {
                    filesToReturn.push(curFile);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    walkDir(resolve(__dirname, dir));
    return filesToReturn;
}
```

Comment: The function throws an `ENOTDIR` exception. Therefore you may need to do some manual bugfixes.

Comment: The fix is posted as different answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77859491/4706711

Answer (score 0):

As @Burak Ayyildiz says you need to manually to traverse the directory and get the paths as an array. But the answer defined from [docu](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/how-to-load-multiple-files-via-vite-config-using-wildcards) has some issues:

```
node:fs:1513
  const result = binding.readdir(
                         ^

Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir '/var/www/html/resources/css/fa-check.css'
    at readdirSync (node:fs:1513:26)
    at walkDir (file:///var/www/html/test.mjs:41:17)
    at getFilesFromDir (file:///var/www/html/test.mjs:51:5)
    at file:///var/www/html/test.mjs:55:20
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:120:12) {
  errno: -20,
  code: 'ENOTDIR',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/var/www/html/resources/css/my.css'
}
```

Therefore, a fix for the function is:

```
import { readdirSync,lstatSync } from 'fs';
import { resolve } from 'path';

function getFilesFromDir(dir, fileTypes) {
    const filesToReturn = [];

    function walkDir(currentPath) {

        if(lstatSync(currentPath).isFile()){
            filesToReturn.push(currentPath);
            return;
        }

        const files = readdirSync(currentPath);
        for (let i in files) {
            const curFile = resolve(currentPath, files[i]);
            if(lstatSync(curFile).isDirectory()){
                walkDir(curFile);
                continue;
            }
            filesToReturn.push(curFile);
        }
    }

    walkDir(resolve(__dirname, dir));
    return filesToReturn;
}
```

That also simplifies the code as well.

## Edit 1

I simplified it a bit as:

```
function getFilesFromDir(dir) {
    const filesToReturn = [];

    function walkDir(currentPath) {

        if(lstatSync(currentPath).isFile()){
            filesToReturn.push(currentPath);
            return;
        }

        const files = readdirSync(currentPath);
        for (let i in files) {
            console.log(files[i]);
            const curFile = resolve(currentPath, files[i]);
            if(lstatSync(curFile).isDirectory()){
                walkDir(curFile);
                continue;
            }
            const file = resolve(currentPath, files[i]);
            filesToReturn.push(file);
        }
    }

    walkDir(resolve(__dirname, dir));
    return filesToReturn;
}
```

I just make it dummier and I include the nessesary files from specific dir.

Comment: Great!!Sorry for that